# Data protection API: key rotation and lifetime of old keys

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm looking at using DP API for password recovery tokens. If a key is rotated, where is the old key stored? How many versions of old keys are kept in the system so that password recovery works for people clicking older recovery email. I'm thinking of setting key lifespan to 14 days.

Framework: .Net core 2.2